# Activity is still appearing despite calling finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my activity A, after starting a new activity B, I call `finish()`.

However when pressing back from B, the old activity A shows up.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: show us you activity B code

Comment: show us your activity B + manifest!

Comment: Can you guys be specific about what you want to see, it is a large class.

Comment: Did you override `onBackPressed()` in activity B?